# Table JOIN is not working as it is supposed to in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I have 2 tables, the first is `users_table` and the second is `friends_table`.

`users_table` contains the information about a user including `banned` column and the `friends_table` is the friendship between users.

Both tables have the column `user_id` so what I want is to retrieve the number of friends for a specific user based on conditions from both tables. The conditions are on `user_id` and `banned`. I want the number of friends to be excluding the banned users, but i am still getting the total number of friends even if a user friend is banned.
Please help me, here are my queries which runs simultaneously to retrieve the friends:

```
$query1 = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM users_table u 
    INNER JOIN friends_table f ON u.user_id = f.user_id 
    WHERE f.user_id = $user_id AND u.banned = 0
";

$query2 = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM users_table u 
    INNER JOIN friends_table f ON u.user_id = f.friend_id
    WHERE f.friend_id = $user_id AND u.banned = 0
";
```

**Edit**
The "users_table" structure :

```
user_id
first_name
last_name
username
email
password
temporarily_banned
banned
```

The "friends_table" structure :

```
friendship_id
user_id
friend_id
friendship_timestamp
```

**Table records examples**

users_table  examples:

```
user_id: 20
first_name: Firas
last_name: Helou
username: firashelou
email: mac_987@hotmail.com
password: *******
temporarily_banned: 0
banned: 0

user_id: 30
first_name: Elie
last_name: Helou
username: eliehelou
email: elie@hotmail.com
password: *******
temporarily_banned: 0
banned: 1

user_id: 22
first_name: Jessy
last_name: Helou
username: jessyhelou
email: jessy@hotmail.com
password: *******
temporarily_banned: 0
banned: 1

user_id: 32
first_name: Jad
last_name: Helou
username: jadhelou
email: jad@hotmail.com
password: *******
temporarily_banned: 0
banned: 0
```

friends_table examples:

```
friendship_id | user_id | friend_id | friendship_timestamp
10                20         30             1534342490
9                 20         22             1533484062
16                32         20             1541619611
```

Comment: Query1 looks OK to me.... If you give us the table structure we will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @XraySensei I added the structure of tables

Comment: Is your friends_table recording each friendship in a bidiriectional way? i.e. user1 and user2 have a frienship so there are two records: one where user1 is the user_id and user2 is the friend_id and another record where user2 is the user_id and user1 the friend_id

Comment: no, what happens is that if user 1 add user 2 as friend, so in friends_table user_id=user1 and friend_id=user2 but the query to fetch the friends checks 2 times

Comment: Then I think that the secon query in @GMB answer is your best option if it fits with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the users table twice to determine if the friend is banned. Query 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_table u
JOIN friends_table f ON f.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN users_table u2 ON u2.user_id = f.friend_id
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id AND u2.banned = 0
```

For the sample data you have provided, this gives the expected results of no friends except for user_id 32.

Query 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_table u
JOIN friends_table f ON f.friend_id = u.user_id
JOIN users_table u2 ON u2.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id AND u2.banned = 0
```

For the sample data you have provided, this gives a different set of results as some banned users have non-banned friends.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48bd848a51f7b47ba24d8415929de6e8)

Comment: still no luck, tried yours, in both the queries at the same time but i still get the total number of friends

Comment: @firasprogrammer was the second query you tried like the one I have just added to my answer?

Comment: yes i retried it again and still getting the same number of total friends, i should get 1, instead i am getting 3 from which 2 are banned

Comment: @firasprogrammer from your description, one of those queries should work. you will probably need to supply some sample data to get this solved

Comment: what do you mean supplied sample data ? i should put names in table you mean ?

Comment: @firasprogrammer yes, show us some sample rows from your table, with the expected output from your query on those rows

Comment: ok is there anyway anyway i can share without typing one by one ? like get the sql or something ?

Comment: @firasprogrammer if you could just copy and paste the results from these queries into the question that would be very helpful.

Comment: Nick i added example records

Comment: @firasprogrammer My second query seems to give the expected result. See the demo link in my edited answer.

Comment: ok I see it is giving the right result, so can you please post final query1 and quer2 ?

Comment: @firasprogrammer I have posted the final query1 and query2. I've also updated the demo with the final query2 as well.

Comment: ok Nick, when i tried exactly your queries i received 2 friends, i should receive 1 but when i altered your queries to this, i received the right result which is 1
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users_table u JOIN friends_table f ON f.user_id = u.user_id JOIN users_table u2 ON u2.user_id = f.friend_id WHERE u.user_id = $user_id AND u2.banned = 0";

Comment: $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users_table u JOIN friends_table f ON f.user_id = u.user_id JOIN users_table u2 ON u2.user_id = f.user_id WHERE f.friend_id = $user_id AND u2.banned = 0";

Comment: How is your query1 different from mine?

Comment: it is different after WHERE

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional `JOIN` on the `user` table to check if the friend is banned.

Your first query becomes :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_table u 
INNER JOIN friends_table f ON f.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN users_table uf ON uf.user_id = f.friend_id AND uf.banned = 0
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id
```

For your second query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_table u 
INNER JOIN friends_table f ON f.friend_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN users_table uf ON uf.user_id = f.user_id AND uf.banned = 0
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id
```

Also it could be possible to merge both query as one, like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_table u 
LEFT JOIN friends_table f1 ON f1.friend_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_table uf1 ON uf.user_id = f1.user_id AND uf1.banned = 0
LEFT JOIN friends_table f2 ON f2.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_table uf2 ON uf2.user_id = f2.friend_id AND uf2.banned = 0
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id AND COALESCE(uf1.id, uf2.id) IS NOT NULL
```

PS : if you are just looking for the *count* of friends, you can use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT *`.

Comment: I tried your query, but it is still giving me the total number of friends and not excluding the banned friends by the admin

Comment: @firasprogrammer : I updated my answer, please check

Comment: my query is now like this, and i received an error 
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users_table u INNER JOIN friends_table f ON u.user_id = f.friend_id INNER JOIN user_tables uf ON uf.user_id = f.user_id AND uf.banned = 0 WHERE f.friend_id = $user_id";

Comment: @firasprogrammer : I fixed a type on`user_tables` instead of `users_table`... Please run my exact query (the one you just showed has a differente `WHERE` clause)

Comment: GMB i added the same query2 u posted but what about query1 what should it be ?

Comment: @firasprogrammer : done, all queries are up to date now

Comment: can you post please final query1 and final query2 so we can be on the same page ?

Comment: @firasprogrammer : that's done already, you have final versions of all queries in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your query appears only to be checking that the user itself is banned.
You'll need to add another join to the users table for the "friend", to check their status as well:

***Assumption: friend_table is just a linking table with no "banned" column

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_table user 
INNER JOIN friends_table f ON u.user_id = f.user_id
INNER JOIN users_table friend on friend.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = $user_id AND 0 NOT IN (u.banned, friend.banned)

SELECT * 
FROM users_table u 
INNER JOIN friends_table f ON u.user_id = f.friend_id
INNER JOIN users_table friend on friend.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE f.friend_id = $user_id AND 0 NOT IN (u.banned, friend.banned)
```

Comment: I added the tables structure, I am listing the friends of the user on his profile page ad showing the number of friends too so what i want is for the logged in user to see only the not banned friends